# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method (on a related entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I am trying to make some code more readable and am not quite grasping how to structure the extension method and/or expression to do it.  We currently have many entities that have a `RecordStatusTypeId` on them (implemented from an interface of `IRecordStatus`)

```
public interface IRecordStatus
{
    int RecordStatusTypeId { get; set; }
    RecordStatusType RecordStatusType { get; set; }
}
```

The goal here is to replace a statement like `.Where(RecordStatusTypeId != (int)RecordStatusTypes.Deleted)` with an extension method like `.ActiveRecords()`

I'm able to accomplish this with the following Extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ActiveRecords<T>(this DbSet<T> entitySet)
    where T : class, IRecordStatus
{
    return entitySet.Where(e => e.RecordStatusTypeId != (int)RecordStatusTypes.Deleted);
}
```

*I have this extension method for `DbSet<T>`, `IQueryable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>`

This works great for statements like `MyDbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.RecordStatusTypeId != (int)RecordStatusTypes.Deleted)`, but I get the error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method" if I try to replace something like:

```
MyDbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.RelatedEntity.Where(re => re.RecordStatusTypeId != (int)RecordStatusTypes.Deleted));
```

with what I'd like to do:

```
MyDbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.RelatedEntity.ActiveRecords().Any());
```

How can I change my Extension Methods (or add an Expression) so that I can filter for active records on the `DbSet` as well as on a related entity inside a linq clause?

Comment: Entity Framework Plus can do this:
https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus

Comment: @CyrilIselin, Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Your method couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. Add `AsEnumerable` to your `Entities` and try again:`MyDbContext.Entities.AsEnumerable().Where...`.

Comment: AsEnumerable would pull all the entities from the DB store into memory. Not something you would want to do against any sizable store.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813671/can-i-use-an-extension-method-inside-a-linq-query

Comment: @PaulZahra i also would provide this link, especially this part

"You can use a custom extension method inside a LINQ query - BUT you cannot use an extension method that the underlying data provider does not know how to execute.". 
The point is that Wyatt is trying to execute extension within the data provider. Am i mistaken? :S

Comment: @BMaximus I believe you are correct, and that the answer lay in constructing the query differently, i.e. not all in one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have done your conversion wrong. 
Should:

```
MyDbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.RelatedEntity.Where(re => re.RecordStatusTypeId != (int)RecordStatusTypes.Deleted));
```

convert to this:

```
MyDbContext.Entities.Where(e => e.RelatedEntity.ActiveRecords().Any());
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  Unfortunately, that was just an error on my part attempting to simplify the post.  I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the exception because `Queryable.Where` expects an expression that can be translated to SQL, and `ActiveRecords` cannot be translated to SQL.

What you need to do is to update the expression to expand the call to `ActiveRecords` to a call to `.Where(e => e.RecordStatusTypeId != (int)RecordStatusTypes.Deleted`).

I am going to provide a draft for a solution that works. It is very specific to the example you provided. You should probably work on it to make it generic.

The following expression visitor will basically change the call to `ActiveRecords` to the call to `Where` with the appropriate expression as an argument:

```
public class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Method.Name == "ActiveRecords")
        {
            var entityType = m.Method.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var whereMethod = genericWhereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

            var param = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
            var expressionToPassToWhere =
                Expression.NotEqual(
                    Expression.Property(param, "RecordStatusTypeId"),
                    Expression.Constant((int)RecordStatusTypes.Deleted));

            Expression newExpression =
                Expression.Call(
                    whereMethod,
                    m.Arguments[0],
                    Expression.Lambda(
                        typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, typeof(bool)),
                        expressionToPassToWhere,
                        param));

            return newExpression;
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(m);
    }

    //This is reference to the open version of `Enumerable.Where`
    private static MethodInfo genericWhereMethod;

    static MyVisitor()
    {
        genericWhereMethod = typeof (Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Where" && x.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
            .Select(x => new {Method = x, Parameters = x.GetParameters()})
            .Where(x => x.Parameters.Length == 2 &&
                        x.Parameters[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
                        x.Parameters[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IEnumerable<>) &&
                        x.Parameters[1].ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
                        x.Parameters[1].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Func<,>))
            .Select(x => x.Method)
            .Single();
    }
}
```

You could then create a special `WhereSpecial` method to visit the expression before passing it to the real `Where` method of `Queryable`:

```
public static class ExtentionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereSpecial<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T,bool>> expression )
    {
        MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor();

        var newBody = visitor.Visit(expression.Body);

        expression = expression.Update(newBody, expression.Parameters);

        return queryable.Where(expression);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
var result = MyDbContext.Entities.WhereSpecial(e => e.RelatedEntity.ActiveRecords().Any());
```

Comment: It seems doing all this defeats whole purpose of using helper ActiveRecords method in the first place :)

Comment: @Evk, that is probably true :) Maybe a more generic visitor that takes in a dictionary of method names and corresponding lambda expressions will make it worth doing all of this.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, I haven't had time to try and explore whether something like this would be worth the effort, but thank you for the answer.  When I have time to revisit, I'll be back to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the main part of the query IQueryable, then tag on the where clause...

Something like:

```
IQueryable temp = from x in MyDbContext.Entities
                  select x;

temp = temp.Where(e => e.RelatedEntity.ActiveRecords().Any());
```

or evaluate the main part and then perform the where in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have this interface applied to a diverse set of entity objects, so I am not able to pull back the contents of the query without first filtering for ActiveRecords (at least not in all cases).